# Find $dy \over dx $ at $t=\frac{\pi}{2}$, given that $x = t + \sin t $ and $y = 2 + \cos t $

Tags: derivatives

$$x = t + \sin t $$
$$y = 2 + \cos t $$

What is the value of $dy \over dx $ for $t = \frac{\pi}{2}$ ?

$t$ cannot be written in terms of $x$ so that I could replace $t$ in function $y$ to calculate its derivative. How would you use solve this question? Please explain why and how that makes sense logically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solve $\frac{dx}{dt}$ and $\frac{dy}{dt}$. Then divide $\frac{dy}{dt}$ by $\frac{dx}{dt}$. Then put $t=\frac{\pi}{2}$ in the expression.

$$\frac{dy}{dt} = -\sin t$$
$$\frac{dx}{dt} = 1+\cos t$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{-\sin t}{1+\cos t}$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}|_{t=\frac{\pi}{2}} = \frac{-\sin \frac{\pi}{2} }{1+\cos \frac{\pi}{2}}=-1$$

Comment: You meant "then divide $dy/dt$ by $dx/dt$, right?

Comment: Yes yes. I changed it.

Comment: I solved this using what you said. Thanks! If you solve the problem, I'll choose your answer as accepted. Right now, it doesn't look like an answer.